# How to find out whether more than 2 vectors are coplanar?

Tags: vectors, mathematics, geometry

Can you please explain me how to find out whether 3 or more vectors in $a\hat i + b\hat j + c\hat k$ format? I know that for 3 vectors, their dot product should be 0 but what is the reason behind this? Please tell me how to determine whether 4 or more vectors in that format are coplanar or not? (Please explain the logic behind that too)

Answer (score 1):

Voted to move to Math.SE.

In 3D orientable manifolds we have an antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf w)$. We usually take
$$\epsilon(\mathbf i,\mathbf j, \mathbf k)=1,$$
And this uniquely specifies all of its behavior, when combined with its total antisymmetry and its tensor aspect (just a fancy way to say that it distributes over addition and scalar multiplication, and that it takes these three vectors and produces a scalar).

So if you have never seen this before, the fact that it is antisymmetric means that
$$\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf w)
=-\epsilon(\mathbf v,\mathbf u, \mathbf w)
=-\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf w, \mathbf v),$$ and so on, every flip of adjacent arguments picks up a new minus sign. In particular this means that $$\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf u, \mathbf w)=\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf w, \mathbf w)=\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf u)=0.$$
Now if the vectors are coplanar that means that they are not linearly independent, $\mathbf w=a\mathbf u + b\mathbf v$. When we distribute over this addition this antisymmetry property solves the problem for us!
$$
\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, a\mathbf u+b\mathbf v)
= a~\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf u)+b~\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf v)\\
=a~0+b~0 =0.$$
So that is the basic reason. (Note that this logic is not complete... We have only proved the if of an “if and only if” and the “only if” part remains to be proven. But at least this shows you why it is plausible.)

The above definition is ultra-compact so it is worth expanding out the case where
$$\mathbf u = a\mathbf i + b \mathbf j + c\mathbf k,\\
\mathbf v=p\mathbf i + q \mathbf j + r\mathbf k,\\
\mathbf w = x\mathbf i + y\mathbf j + z\mathbf k.$$
Distributing over the 27 terms, then removing the ones that duplicate $i,j,k$ gives only 6 terms that survive, 3 of which have +1 and three of which have -1, once we swap the argument pairs back to the $i,j,k$ order:
$$
\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf w)=aqz+brx+cpy-ary-bpz-cqx.$$based on that expansion you can also write this in some other ways that do not show off this beautiful anti-symmetry at first, like
$$
\epsilon(\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf w)=
\mathbf u\cdot(\mathbf v \times \mathbf w)$$
The generalization to four vectors is a little more complicated than it seems at first, basically you just want to choose two vectors that are not pointing in the same direction, so that they define a plane, and then every other vector can be inserted into that triple product one by one, $\epsilon(\mathbf w_i, \mathbf u,\mathbf v)=0$.

The generalizations to $n$-dimensiomal space are hopefully also pretty straightforward in this language, you can either choose to detect that a bunch of things all occupy the same $n-1$-hypersurface, using the same anti-symmetric tensor, or you could choose to detect that they occupy the same 2-surface, which is probably easier if you just use straight dot products at that point... Subtract $$\mathbf w_i\mapsto\mathbf w_i - \mathbf u\frac{\mathbf u\cdot \mathbf w_i}/{\mathbf u\cdot \mathbf u}.$$
The remaining vectors must be colinear as they are all perpendicular to the first vector. This is usually pretty quick to check directly...